# The EU-Uk trade deal ratification by national parliaments

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union, brexit, trade

What would follow if any of the national parliaments refused to ratify the EU-UK trade agreement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only parliaments that have to ratify it are the UK and the European,  individual EU countries are not required to approve it.

The odds of either of these rejecting it are very small. In the case of the EU Parliament, if it were to reject it, then it would be asked to vote again and again until it gave the "right" answer.  See the various referendums on EU issues over the last two decades (with the exception of Brexit).

Comment: Has this already been decided? I have only found sources not very clear on whether national parliaments will or will not need to ratify the agreement, e.g. [here](https://www.instituteforgovernment.org.uk/explainers/future-relationship-eu-ratification) from November 2020

Comment: Yes- see the next steps outlined here https://ec.europa.eu/commission/presscorner/detail/en/ip_20_2531

Comment: @krenkz This is almost certainly means this is considered an "EU-only" instead of a "mixed" agreement. See https://trade.ec.europa.eu/doclib/docs/2012/june/tradoc_149616.pdf and  http://respect.eui.eu/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2020/05/Mixity.pdf for more on the distinction. CETA was an example of the latter, which is why took ages to finalize. The latter paper has a table on p.8 with what roughly decides if an agreement is "mixt" or not.

Comment: @krenkz: the EU-Japan treaty [was](https://www.instituteforgovernment.org.uk/explainers/future-relationship-eu-ratification) an EU-only one and from what I've read in the press it covered a bit *more* than this latest EU-UK one does...

Comment: "In the case of the EU Parliament, if it were to reject it, then it would be asked to vote again and again until it gave the "right" answer." I'm not sure that EU Parlimentary Procedure allows for such persistent re-votes on the exact same issue as you state.

Comment: @ouflak I'm sure they don't nevertheless the EU Parliament will not be allowed to block this treaty regardless.